# translate mainframe data packet to an XML packet in .net

Tags: .net, xml, mainframe, packet

is there a way to translate mainframe data packet Format(Flat Files,CVS) to an XML/NIEM Format in .net? or any suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I think you are going to need to provide more details about what you mean by "mainframe data packet" before anyone can help you...

Comment: Ditto to what @Scrappydog said. Which mainframe OS, what data packet format, what character encoding, what data do you want to extract from it, what validation is required, any requirements on the XML, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shadow](http://www.datadirect.com/solutions/xml/mainframe-integration/index.ssp) makes a product that does mainframe-to-XML.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done with any ETL tool.  The one that most (all?) mainframe shops will have access to is SYNCSORT.  It can be caused to output XML based on an instream description of the fields.